# difference between PacketLoss and BitRate in the API Opentok?

Tags: opentok, tokbox, bitrate, packet-loss

In the Opentok tool that is the session inspector shows graphs with the losses that had the users who were connected in a session, I would like to know what is the difference between PakectLoss and BitRate?

Answer (score 0):

Stiven,

Bit-rate: The number of bits per seconds stream sends.

Packet loss: The discarding of packets(Packets are units of data in the Network Layer) in a network when a router or other network device is overloaded and can't accept additional packet at given moment.

Thanks!